# How do you set the size of a Silverlight OOB application window?

Tags: silverlight

When ever I launch my Silverlight Out-of-Browser application the window size does not match my layout.  I've seen ways to provide different size icons using the XML file for `Deployment.ApplicationIdentity`, but not to specify size of window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on the project go to properties click out of browser settings. there you can specify

Answer (score 1):

This is managed via the [Application Manifest file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb851612.aspx).

```
<SilverlightApp>
  <source>XAML or XAP file</source>
  <version>1.0 | 2.0</version>
  <width>[value in browser units or percentage]</width>
  <height>[value in browser units or percentage]</height>
</SilverlightApp>
```